# android checkbox is checked always true

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox

I defined a checkbox and assigned no value to it.
Every time I click on it and print the value of checkbox, it shows `true` every time.

I put the result in the SharedPreferences and then retrieved it.
Why is it always `true`?

```
public class CallAndSms extends Activity{
static SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
static     Context context ;
static ListView lv;
static CallAndSmsAdaptor adapter;
static ArrayList<String> AllData= new ArrayList<String>();
CheckBox save;
static SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=null;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    setContentView(R.layout.sms_call);
     preferences = getSharedPreferences("modes",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     editor = preferences.edit();



    save= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.save);


    save.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("save", true));



    context=this;


     save.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            if ( save.isChecked()){
                Log.i("save save", save.isChecked()+"");

                  editor.putBoolean("save", true);

            }

            else 

                  {editor.putBoolean("save", false);}

            Log.i("pref", preferences.getBoolean("save", true)+"");


        }
    });


 }
 }
```

Comment: because you have passed the default value in when getting value from shared preferences  with key "save" to true. So by default your checkbox is checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never `apply()` (or `commit()`) your Preference changes.
Therefore, you always retrieve the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You must **commit** your [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference) after editing.

```
save.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
           if ( save.isChecked()){
              Log.i("save save", save.isChecked()+"");
              editor.putBoolean("save", true);
              editor.commit();
           }else{
              editor.putBoolean("save", false);
              editor.commit();
           }
              Log.i("pref", preferences.getBoolean("save", true)+"");
        }
    });
```